# How to pass the state value of a component to another component?

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm adding a search bar to a page in my movie review application. The page displays all the review posts for one specific movie. The prop "reviews" contains all the existing reviews. I was stuck with figuring out how to pass the value of the state "filteredResults" from the useSearch hook to the ReviewPost component so that I could display the filteredResults data on the page.

Reviews Card:

```
export const Reviews = ({ reviews }) => (
  <div>
        {reviews.map((review, i) => (
          <div key={i}>{review}</div>
        ))}
  </div>
)
```

Search Bar for the Reviews:

```
export const ReviewSearchBar = ({ reviews }) => {
  const { onChange, textValue } = useSearch({ reviews })

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        value={textValue}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: don't  hide the code from question, it may be useful for other people to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `const { onChange, textValue, filteredResults } = useSearch({ reviews })` to Parent component and from Parent pass props `onChange, textValue` to `ReviewSearchBar` and prop `filteredResults` to `ReviewPosts` component

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Redux to manage global state.